# How do I create a class property (Get) to be an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I would like to set a Get property for a class in vba to be an array. How do I do this.

in the class module

```
Dim pdbCGX As Double
Dim pdbCGY As Double
Dim pdbCGZ As Double

Public Property Get TheCGv() As Double
    TheCGv(0) = pdbCGX
    TheCGv(1) = pdbCGY
    TheCGv(2) = pdbCGZ
End Property
```

'allocation of data in a sub in the class

```
pdbCGX = CDbl(extracteddata1)
pdbCGY = CDbl(extracteddata2)
pdbCGZ = CDbl(extracteddata3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do it like that

```
Option Explicit

Dim pdbCGX As Double
Dim pdbCGY As Double
Dim pdbCGZ As Double


Public Property Get TheCGv() As Variant

Dim v(0 To 2) As Double

    v(0) = pdbCGX
    v(1) = pdbCGY
    v(2) = pdbCGZ

    TheCGv = v

End Property
```

If you want to return an array with data type double your code could look like that

```
Option Explicit

Dim pdbCGX As Double
Dim pdbCGY As Double
Dim pdbCGZ As Double


Public Property Get TheCGv() As Double()

    Dim v(0 To 2) As Double

    v(0) = pdbCGX
    v(1) = pdbCGY
    v(2) = pdbCGZ

    TheCGv = v

End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this problem is to not use an array, but instead put a scripting.Dictionary inside the class and also set up an enumeration to ensure that reading and writing to the scripting .Dictionary is strongly typed.

The code below is a wrapper class for a Scripting.dictionary to which I've added an Enum based on your post above.

```
Option Explicit
' Strongly typed wrapper for the Scripting.Dictionary
' Replace KeyType with the Type for the Key to be used  -> done using pdb 
' Replace ValueType with the Type for the Values to be used - done using Double

Public Enum pdb

    CGX
    CGY
    CGZ

End Enum

Private Type State
    Host                        As Scripting.Dictionary
End Type

Private s                       As State


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    'Set s.Host = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set s.Host = New Scripting.Dictionary

End Sub


'@Description("Add: Adds a new key/item pair to a Dictionary object").
Public Sub Add(ByVal Key As pdb, ByVal Value As Double)
    s.Host.Add Key, Value
End Sub

'@Description("Count: Returns the number of key/item pairs in a Dictionary object.")
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = s.Host.Count
End Function


'@Description("CompareMode: Sets or returns the comparison mode for comparing keys in a Dictionary object.")
Public Property Get CompareMode() As Scripting.CompareMethod
    CompareMode = s.Host.CompareMode
End Property

Public Property Let CompareMode(ByVal Compare As Scripting.CompareMethod)
    s.Host.CompareMode = Compare
End Property


'@Description("Exists  Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a specified key exists in the Dictionary object.)
Public Function Exists(ByVal Key As pdb) As Boolean
    Exists = s.Host.Exists(Key)
End Function


'@Description("Item: Get or returns the value of an item in a Dictionary object.")
'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Item(ByVal Key As pdb)
    Item = s.Host(Key)
End Property

' Delete Let or Set depending if Value is a primitive or object type
Public Property Let Item(ByVal Key As pdb, ByVal Value As Double)
    s.Host(Key) = Value
End Property

Public Property Set Item(ByVal Key As pdb, ByVal Value As Double)
    Set s.Host(Key) = Value
End Property


'@Description("'Items: Returns an array of all the items in a Dictionary object.")
Public Function Items() As Variant
    Items = s.Host.Items
End Function


'@Description("Key Sets a new key value for an existing key value in a Dictionary object.")
Public Sub Key(ByVal OldKey As pdb, ByVal NewKey As pdb)
    s.Host.Key(OldKey) = NewKey
End Sub


'@Description("Keys    Returns an array of all the keys in a Dictionary object.")
Public Function Keys() As Variant
    Keys = s.Host.Keys()
End Function


'@Description("Remove  Removes one specified key/item pair from the Dictionary object.")
Public Sub Remove(ByVal Key As pdb)
    s.Host.Remove (Key)
End Sub


'@Description("RemoveAll: Removes all the key/item pairs in the Dictionary object.")
Public Sub RemoveAll()
    s.Host.RemoveAll
End Sub
```

If you do require an array, for example you are putting values back into Excel, then the values in the scripting dictionary can be obtained as an Array from the .Items method.